# Is there a way to execute a script no matters where it is?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to make a script that needs be able to be called no matters where it is. It is for locate itself in the disk and export a variable to another script.
I already have the code fragment for locate itself but the problem is that normally the shell files (.sh) are launched specifying the path to it.
Any help or idea is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What if someone creates another script with the same name as yours, and puts it in a different directory?  How should the system know which one to run?

Comment: You could use something like `locate` or `find` to find it in the filesystem, or you could add all likely directories to the `PATH` environment variable.  But these all have serious risks.  The better answer is "don't do this, install the script in a known location instead".  This sounds very much like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 options here:

1)You can add the path of the script to the system path or to the path of the user that will run the script. To do this you can:

-Edit `/etc/profile` script and change the PATH variables so they also contain the path where the script resides. This would add the your script directory to the system path.

-Edit `/home/user/.bashrc` and ad the following line:

```
export PATH="/yourpath:$PATH"
```

where `/yourpath` is the path where your script resides, and *user* is the user that will run the script. This would add the script path to the PATH of the user that will run the script.

2. For the second option, you can copy the script to a directory that is already on the system path.

you can check what is on the system path by looking at how `PATH` is defined in `/etc/profile`

Whichever option you user, remember also to configure the script permissions so the users that need to, can execute it.

Comment: That was not for what i was looking for but it also is a way to do it, thank you!